# Close app and open on launcher

Tags: android

I'm learning to develop in android and I need your help.
This is what I use to close my app...

```
boolean twice;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(twice) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    twice = true;
    toastMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.msg0a));
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            twice = false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

The problem is when I return to my app it open in last activity and I whant it open in LAUNCHER activity.

EDIT: The reason for this is: I have an activity where user can logout from account and with destiny in login activity. After logout, when user open my app he must pass to login activity again and again while he don´t login.

Comment: simply call finish(); inside onBackPressed()

Comment: @dcd4u2: Can you tell us how you are coming back to app? Via app icon at home or recent screen?

Comment: @AndiGeeky: Yes, via icon at home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go through how [Activity, Tasks and Back stack works in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

Now let's work on your scenario, If I am assuming right from your question, What you want is:

1. When user taps 'twice' on **Back** button in Android, You want to close the app.
2. After closing app, when user come back to your app by,

   - Tapping **App launcher** from home screen or,
   - From **Recents**

**Solution:**
Create an intent with CLEAR_TASK and NEW_TASK flag and destined activity as a Launcher Activity.

**TransparentActivity.java**

```
public class TransparentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int flag = (getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
        if (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY == flag) {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
            getApplication().startActivity(intent);
        }

        finish();
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUtils.java**

```
public static void kill(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TransparentActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Just call below line to exit your app:

```
ApplicationUtils.kill();
```

Above call will kill your app and when you start from either option mentioned above, It will start from launcher. :)

Comment: Wonderfull, it works like a charm. Thank you, AndiGeeky!

Comment: @dcd4u2: Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

It is strongly advised to never called `System.exit(0);`, you should let Android handle if your application needs to be killed or not.

Try something like this, it'll give you control over the delay between back presses, and is very readable.

```
// Time in millis between presses.
private final static int BACK_EXIT_DELAY = 2000; 

private long backLastPress = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if( now - backLastPress < BACK_EXIT_DELAY ) {
        finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeToast( this, "Press back again to exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        backLastPress = now;
    }
}
```